# VBA Key Already Associated With Collection

Tags: excel, excel-2003, excel-2013, vba

I'm using the code below to extract data from a master "All Data" sheet to multiple sheets i.e. 'Set ws'.

```
Sub ForecastExtract()

    Dim ad As Worksheet
    Dim AFTE As Single
    Dim BlnProjExists As Boolean
    Dim bottomB As Integer
    Dim ColDates As New Collection
    Dim Flex As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim JRole As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim m As Long
    Dim OVH As Worksheet
    Dim PDate As Date
    Dim PLOB As String
    Dim Portfolio As String
    Dim PRO As Worksheet
    Dim Project As String
    Dim RLOB As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim RngDates As Range
    Dim Task As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Const StartRow As Long = 8

    Set ad = Sheets("All Data")

    bottomB = ad.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each rng In ad.Range("B8:B" & bottomB)

        Set ws = Sheets(rng.Value)

    For i = 3 To ws.Cells(StartRow - 1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        m = m + 1
        ColDates.Add m, ws.Cells(StartRow - 1, i).Text
    Next i

    On Error Resume Next
    With Sheets("All Data").Range("I7")
        For i = 1 To .CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1
            Portfolio = .Offset(i, -7)
            PLOB = .Offset(i, -6)
            RLOB = .Offset(i, -5)
            JRole = .Offset(i, -2)
            Project = .Offset(i, 0)
            PCode = .Offset(i, 1)
            Task = .Offset(i, 3)
            PDate = .Offset(i, 4)
            FFTE = .Offset(i, 6)
            AFTE = .Offset(i, 8)
            Flex = .Offset(i, 9)

            If Portfolio = ws.Name And InStr(.Offset(i, -2), "Consultancy & Innovation") = 0 And _
            InStr(.Offset(i, 0), "TM - DIR") > 0 And _
            .Offset(i, 4).Value >= Application.Min(ws.Rows(7)) And Flex = "Yes" Then
                Portfolio = .Offset(i, -7)
                Task = .Offset(i, 3)

                With ws.Range("B7")
                    If .CurrentRegion.Rows.Count = 1 Then
                        .Offset(1, 0) = Portfolio
                        j = 1
                    Else
                        BlnProjExists = False
                        For j = 1 To .CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1
                            If .Offset(j, 0) = Portfolio Then
                                BlnProjExists = True
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next j
                        If BlnProjExists = False Then
                            .Offset(j, 0) = Portfolio
                        End If

                        On Error Resume Next
                    m = ColDates(Format(PDate, "mmm yy"))
                    If Err = 0 Then .Offset(j, m) = .Offset(j, m) + FFTE
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        Next i
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    Next rng
    End Sub
```

### **The problem**

When the code moves to the second sheet to paste the extracted data, I receive the following error:

`This key is already associated with an element of this collection`

Debug highlighs the following line as the cause:

`ColDates.Add m, ws.Cells(StartRow - 1, i).Text`

I've been through the internet and some solutions to similar posts suggest adding the `On error Resume Next...` statement whereas as other do not, so I'm not sure which approach to take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collections are different than dictionary. Any how looking at your code, I think using dictionary will be enough.

Anyway, for collection in your code, you need to add something in your key part to make it unique.

In `ColDates.Add m, ws.Cells(StartRow - 1, i).Text`, the key is `ws.Cells(StartRow - 1, i).Text`. Now in second sheet your data must be duplicate, hence the issue.

One possible solution is to add counter in the key:

`ColDates.Add m, ws.Cells(StartRow - 1, i).Text & CStr(m)`